# Group and sum values of NSDictionary by month where key is NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, nsmutabledictionary, ordereddictionary

I have a dictionary with the following structure,

```
arrayOne =     {
    "2015-11-09T00:00:00.000Z" = 1;
    "2015-11-16T00:00:00.000Z" = 2;
    "2015-11-23T00:00:00.000Z" = 3;
    "2015-11-30T00:00:00.000Z" = 4;
    "2015-12-07T00:00:00.000Z" = 5;
    "2015-12-14T00:00:00.000Z" = 6;
    "2015-12-21T00:00:00.000Z" = 7;
    "2015-12-28T00:00:00.000Z" = 8;
    "2016-01-04T00:00:00.000Z" = 9;
    "2016-01-11T00:00:00.000Z" = 1;
    "2016-01-18T00:00:00.000Z" = 2;
    "2016-01-25T00:00:00.000Z" = 3;
```

}

I'd like to create another dictionary with values like,

```
arrayTWo = {

        "November" = 10;
        "December" = 26;
        "January"  = 15;        
    }
```

I tried by getting month values of dates in a separate array and values in a separate array and then tried to get those in a nsmutabledictionary, but it does not assign value for duplicate keys and got a solution like

```
arrayTWo = {

    "November" = 4;
    "December" = 8;
    "January"  = 3;        
}
```

I couldn't find a better way, Any options are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code that you have that currently isn't quite working?

Comment: Basically it looks like you need to do something like `arrayTwo[month] = arrayTwo[month] + value` instead of `arrayTwo[month] = value`.  This is pseudo-code as you'll probably need to do some boxing/unboxing of the `NSNumber`.

Comment: Are you trying to count how many times a date for each month appears, and that is what you want your end result to be?

Comment: @mttrb thank you so much for the effort, I got it working with vadian 's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it uses `NSDateFormatter` to get the month name from the date, it's localized depending on the current locale. If your locale is not english and you need to get the english month names uncomment the line to set the locale explicitly.

The logic is simple:

Enumerate the dictionary, If the key (month) exists, add the value, if it doesn't create the key

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];      
formatter.dateFormat = @"MMMM";
// formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSDate *key in arrayOne.allKeys) {
  NSString *month = [formatter stringFromDate:key];
  if (result[month] == nil) {
    result[month] = arrayOne[key];
  } else {
    NSInteger value = [result[month] integerValue];
    result[month] = @(value + [arrayOne[key] integerValue]);
  }
}
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Comment: Thank you for the block, I got it working after a bit of date formatter conversions on arrayOne's keys, to get month only. Thanks again, you saved a lot  of time.